# swig: make c++ objects printable in perl?

Tags: c++, perl, swig

I'm creating perl bindings for my c++ classes with SWIG. Each class has a `printMe(std::ostream&)` method in C++ for nice output. Can I make my classes printable in Perl so the following code would produce this nice output?

```
my $v = new MyVector();
print $v;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you write here, probably not. It looks like the `printMe()` method actually sends the formatted string to an output stream, which is not so useful. What you'd need is a method that creates the string and then returns it, so it can be passed up to the Perl level and later given as an argument to Perl's `print` builtin.

If there is a C++ method that returns a suitable string form, you'll want to read `perldoc overload` to learn how to make using it more convenient.

Comment: Making this `to_string` method is trivial: `std::ostringstream strm; printMe(strm); return strm.str();` The problem is I cannot find what exactly should I overload so perl could understand the `print $v;` construct.

Comment: The stringification operator. Something like `use overload '""' => \&to_string;`